# Cognito Authorize Endpoint For federated users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using the cognito authorize endpoint and using 'identity_provider' query parameter to bypass the hosted UI and allowing users to authenticate directly with their identity provider (in this case, Google). When a user is already authenticated with Google and clicks on "Sign in with Google" again, I want to provide them with the option to select from multiple Google accounts rather than automatically signing them in.

I expect a google signin page with multiple account selection